# Error 54046 occurred at disk power-on lifetime

Tags: hard-drive

I am using Ubuntu 20. Few days ago, OS was failed to boot and giving harddisk error. So I boot Ubuntu from PenDrive and run smartctl to perform health check of the disk.

**Information of Hard Disk:**

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD10JPVX-75JC3T0
Serial Number:    WXV1EC4LP8RX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 65b053a63
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jul 19 15:52:12 2020 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (18420) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 206) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   193   193   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       123282
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   182   177   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1875
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2813
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   133   133   140    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 2829
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   163   143   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       7829
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2410
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       170
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       312
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   188   188   000    Old_age   Always       -       37465
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   103   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       44
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       2654
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       65318
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   001   001   000    Old_age   Offline      -       167119
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       5946
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       23841324672
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       37145294344
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 54049 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 54049 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6727 hours (280 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 03 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 90 03 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:01.384  SET FEATURES [Disable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:01.384  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef 90 03 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:00.494  SET FEATURES [Disable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:00.494  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

Error 54048 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6727 hours (280 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 00 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:01.384  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef 90 03 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:00.494  SET FEATURES [Disable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:00.494  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

Error 54047 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6727 hours (280 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 03 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 90 03 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:00.494  SET FEATURES [Disable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:00.494  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef 90 03 00 00 00 a0 00      01:56:59.625  SET FEATURES [Disable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:56:59.624  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

Error 54046 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6727 hours (280 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 00 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:57:00.494  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef 90 03 00 00 00 a0 00      01:56:59.625  SET FEATURES [Disable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:56:59.624  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

Error 54045 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6727 hours (280 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 03 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 90 03 00 00 00 a0 00      01:56:59.625  SET FEATURES [Disable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:56:59.624  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef 90 03 00 00 00 a0 00      01:56:58.757  SET FEATURES [Disable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:56:58.756  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Conveyance offline  Completed: unknown failure    90%      6694         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: unknown failure    90%      6694         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      6694         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      6694         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: unknown failure    90%      5657         -
# 6  Conveyance offline  Completed: unknown failure    90%      5657         -
# 7  Extended offline    Completed: unknown failure    90%      5656         -
# 8  Conveyance offline  Completed: unknown failure    90%      5535         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    10%      5473         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed: unknown failure    90%      5309         -
#11  Conveyance offline  Aborted by host               90%      5309         -
#12  Short offline       Aborted by host               10%      4768         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4428         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4328         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4260         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4231         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4205         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2644         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2615         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2563         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1995         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

**Error Message**

> Error 54046 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6727 hours (280 days +
> 7 hours)

Please let me know if more information is required and help me to resolve the issue or repair the disk if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This disk has failed, as indicated in the smartctl output. There is not a "repair" to be done to it. The only thing to be done is to replace the disk. If the disk is still within its warranty period, you can return it to the manufacturer under warranty if you wish and your security policies allow it.